# Closing a question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently I asked a question which was closed as Duplicate.

My question was indeed a Duplicate of that old question(the old question was dated 2009) but as one of the people who closed the question also admitted, the answer in that old question does not work anymore.

My question is what's the best approach in such cases? The old question is 2009 so there is little hope anyone look and update it again.

On the other hand, if this new duplicate question stays open there is a chance someone provides a current and working solution .

Comment: You post a question, linking the duplicate, saying "I know that this question was asked here, but because of [insert reason], it doesn't work for me (or anymore, in your case)"

Comment: I should post the question here?

Comment: @S.Nash on stack I mean :). Since your question is ALREADY as a dupe, you could edit it, then have it reopened

Comment: I did edit it . I hope they re-open it. I tried that old solution and it does not work,

Comment: Why not place a bounty on the original? That way, if there's a new answer, it ends up in the same place, so other people don't have to go trawling around multiple questions to find the one that matches their needs.

Comment: Sounds like you are saying the accepted answer didn't work.  But do any of the others work?  There are 13 answers, 2 of which with 60+ votes.in addition to the accepted answer

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's a good suggestion but probably not useful to someone who has low reputation.

Comment: The privilege is unlocked from 75 rep; you have enough to give away 250 without even losing any of your existing privileges.

Comment: A question about closing duplicate questions was closed as being a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the technologies that you're using are different enough that the answer to the old question doesn't work anymore, then your question is **not** a duplicate of the old question.

You're using a different version of the technology than the older question was asking about.

Just make sure that you tag your question properly, including a tag for the new technology, to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: Agreed. My Client side software alone IE11 is much different from browsers was used in 2009. Thanks for suggestion I will update the question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your question is *not answerable*.  You say that "the answer in that old question doesn't work anymore," but you leave out the **most important part:**

> Basically there is no reliable way to force a new window instead of a new tab, or vice-versa; it is ultimately under user control

So, your question is asking for a way to do something that is not possible anymore.  The duplicate question contains details about *why this is true*, and is being used as the canonical question for this reason.

Comment: +1 for looking what question prompted this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123877/how-javascript-window-open-opens-a-window-in-a-popup-window, if anyone wonders). Which leads to a different answer than just taking it at face-value.

Comment: Well, If one person says there is no reliable way does no mean there is not way to do it actually. So I have serious doubt that opening a windows as a pop up window is impossible.

Comment: @SNash You can only create a new window, you cannot tell that browser to not make it a tab.

Comment: @Tiny giant but remember that this was possible at least in 2009

Comment: Yes it was, but it is not now. You're question doesn't ask why its not possible, it asks for a solution to a problem which has no solution